# Pulp Python linear programming problem seems to ignore my constraints

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

I have a Python script (Pulp library) for allocating funds among a number of clients depending on their current level of funding (gap/requirements) and their membership to priority groups. However, I am not receiving the expected results.
In particular, I want:

1. All allocations must be positive and their sum should be equal to the total available money I have.
2. I want to minimize the target funding gap for the most vulnerable group (group A) and then I want that the target gap % in the less vulnerable group increase of 10%: (for group B = funding gap A times 1.1, for group C = funding gap B times 1.1...).

I have tried this:

```
"""
MULTI-OBJECTIVE LINEAR OPTIMIZATION PROBLEM
(FG-01-2023)


---PROBLEM DESCRIPTION
#n Projects, each with its own Requirements (expressed in USD), Gap (expressed in USD) and Allocation (in USD).
Allocation represents the amount of extra resources (in USD) each project is going receiving as part of the exercise.
Initial value for Project(i) Allocation = 0

For each project we define
    Project(i) GAP% =  (Gap - Allocation)/Requirements

Projects are grouped by Priority (Prioritization Group) based on Vulnerability criteria (Group A is higher priority,
followed by B, C, and so on).

We are projecting to receive some additional funding, which we want to distribute among projects.

    Project(i) Allocation += Portion of additional funding allocated to Project(i)


---OBJECTIVES
Allocate the entire additional funding:
- Minimize the portion of Additional Funding which is not allocated to Projects   --> ideally reduce to 0
Reduce the maximum GAP% within each priority group
- Minimize the Maximum GAP% within each priority group --> Ideally, if there are sufficient funds, reduce all GAP% to 0


---CONSTRAINTS
Allocations to individual projects must be: 1) non-negative, and 2) not greater than the Project's initial Gap.
Sum of allocations to individual projects cannot be greater than the total additional funding
Allocations to Projects should not cause Max GAP% of a lower priority group to become lower than Max GAP% of a higher
priority group


---IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
This script tries to use Python's PuLP library to implement the optimization model.
Documentation: https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/
PuLP can use a variety of "solvers". The script start with the default one (CBC MILP).
A better approach may be to use a different optimization library that better supports multi-objective:
- pulp-or: Operations Research, provides --> pulp.generate_pareto_front() function
- DEAP: Distributed Evolutionary Algorithms
- PyGMO: Python Parallel Global Multiobjective Optimizer --> non_dominated_front_mo() function
- nsga2: Non-dominated Sorting Genetic Algorithm 2 --> nsga2.nsga2() function



---VERSIONS
Python 3.10
PuLP 2.7.0


---INSTRUCTIONS
The Script asks the user to import data from an input Excel file with four columns:
- Project Name
- Group
- Requirements
- GAP
It also asks for the AMOUNT to be allocated
The result can be output to console and/or exported to an Excel file named "optimization_results_(AMOUNT)_TIMESTAMP"

---OUTSTANDIG IMPLEMENTATION PROBLEMS
- The problem is reduced to a single-objective one by working on a linear combination of the two objective functions
- If clients with a GAP but no requirements ar not excluded (parameter-controlled) the model doesn't work correctly
- delta_gap is an externally imposed parameter (forces some distance between max % GAP of two consecutive prioritization
 groups)
"""



"""
PACKAGES
"""
import pulp
from pulp import LpVariable, LpAffineExpression
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime
import openpyxl




"""
CONFIGURATION PARAMETERS
"""
delta_gap = 1.1



"""
FUNCTIONS
"""
def select_input_file():
    # Select the input file to upload

    # Create a file selection dialog
    layout = [[sg.Text('Select a file:')],
              [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
              [sg.Checkbox('Print output to console')],
              [sg.Checkbox('Save output to Excel file', default=True)],
              [sg.Checkbox('Do not allocate funding to clients with 0 Requirements', default=True)],
              [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]


    # Create the window
    window = sg.Window('File Selection Dialog', layout)
    event, values = window.read()

    # Close the window
    window.close()

    # Get the selected file path from the values dictionary
    input_file = values[0]
    print_to_console = values[1]
    print_to_excel = values[2]
    skip_zero_requirements = values[3]

    return input_file, print_to_console, print_to_excel, skip_zero_requirements

def get_additional_funding():
    # Let the user indicate the amount of additional funding to be allocated

    # Create a data entry dialog
    layout = [[sg.Text('Enter the expected funding amount:')],
              [sg.InputText(key='input')],
              [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]

    # Create the window
    window = sg.Window('Expected Funding', layout)
    event, values = window.read()

    # Close the window
    window.close()

    # Get the selected file path from the values dictionary
    input_value = values['input']
    return (input_value)

def print_to_console(output):

    for line in output:
        print(line)
    # # Print the Problem representation in PuLP
    # print('Problem Statements')
    # print(lp_prob)
    #
    #
    # # Print the Optimization Results
    # print("Status:", pulp.LpStatus[lp_prob.status])
    # print("Objective value:", pulp.value(lp_prob.objective))
    #
    # # Print the headings of the output table
    # print("Project Name\tPriority Group\tRequirements\tInitial Gap\tInitial Gap %\tAllocation\tNew Gap\tNew Gap %")
    # total_allocation = 0
    # for i in range(n):
    #     # Calculate the new gap and the new gap percentage
    #     new_gap = gap[i] - allocation[project_names[i]].value()
    #     if requirements[i] == 0:
    #         new_gap_percentage = 0
    #     else:
    #         new_gap_percentage = new_gap / requirements[i]
    #
    #     # Print project data on one line
    #     print(f"{project_names[i]}\t{priority[i]}\t{requirements[i]:>10}\t{gap[i]:>10}\t{gap_percentage[i]:>10.2f}\t{allocation[project_names[i]].value():>10}\t{new_gap:>10}\t{new_gap_percentage:>10.2f}")
    #     total_allocation += allocation[project_names[i]].value()
    #
    # print('total allocation: ' + str(total_allocation))
    # #print('Final Value of the Group Decision Variables')
    # #for group in priority_groups:
    # #        print(max_gap_percentage[group] + " - " + max_gap_percentage[group].value())

def print_to_excel(output):
    # get current date and time
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Format the date and time as a string
    timestamp = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    # Create the filename with the timestamp
    filename = f'optimization_results_({additional_funding})_{timestamp}.xlsx'
    # Create a list of dictionaries, each containing the data for one project
    project_data = []
    for i in range(n):
        # Calculate the new gap and the new gap percentage
        new_gap = gap[i] - allocation[project_names[i]].value()
        if requirements[i] == 0:
            new_gap_percentage = 0
        else:
            new_gap_percentage = new_gap / requirements[i]
        # Create a dictionary for the project data
        data = {
            'Project Name': project_names[i],
            'Priority Group': priority[i],
            'Requirements': requirements[i],
            'Initial Gap': gap[i],
            'Initial Gap %': gap_percentage[i],
            'Allocation': allocation[project_names[i]].value(),
            'New Gap': new_gap,
            'New Gap %': new_gap_percentage
        }
        project_data.append(data)

    # Create a DataFrame from the project data
    df = pd.DataFrame(project_data)

    # Create an ExcelWriter object
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)

    # Write the DataFrame to the Excel file
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

    # Get the worksheet object
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

    # Rename the worksheet to "Optimization Results"
    worksheet.title = "Optimization Results"

    # Hide the gridlines
    worksheet.gridlines = False

    # Set the header row height
    worksheet.row_dimensions[1].height = 20

    # Freeze the header row
    worksheet.freeze_panes = 'A2'

    # Make the top row bold
    for cell in worksheet[1]:
        cell.font = openpyxl.styles.Font(bold=True)

    # Set the column widths for all columns
    worksheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 20 # Project
    worksheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 20 # Priority
    worksheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = 20 # Requirements USD
    worksheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = 20 # Ininitial Gap USD
    worksheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = 20 # Initial Gap %
    worksheet.column_dimensions['F'].width = 20 # Allocation USD
    worksheet.column_dimensions['G'].width = 20 # New Gap USD
    worksheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = 20 # New Gap %

    # Get the number of rows in the worksheet
    num_rows = worksheet.max_row

    # Iterate over all the rows in the "Initial Gap" column
    for row in range(2, num_rows + 1):
        # Set the number format for the cell in colu,ns C, D, F, and G
        worksheet[f'C{row}'].number_format = '#,##0'
        worksheet[f'D{row}'].number_format = '#,##0'
        worksheet[f'F{row}'].number_format = '#,##0'
        worksheet[f'G{row}'].number_format = '#,##0'
        # Set the number format for the cell in column E and H
        worksheet[f'E{row}'].number_format = '0.00%'
        worksheet[f'H{row}'].number_format = '0.00%'

    # Set the filters on the header row
    worksheet.auto_filter.ref = "A1:H1"

    # Get the workbook object
    workbook = writer.book

    # Create a new worksheet
    worksheet2 = workbook.create_sheet("Execution Log")

    row = 1
    # Iterate over the elements of the output list
    for element in output:
        # Check if the element is a PuLP object
        if isinstance(element, pulp.LpProblem):
            # Get the string representation of the object
            string = str(element)
            # Split the string into lines
            lines = string.split('\n')
            # Iterate over the lines
            for line in lines:
                # Write the line to the worksheet
                cell = openpyxl.cell.Cell(worksheet2, value=line)
                worksheet2.append([cell])
        else:
            # Write the element to the worksheet as-is
            cell = openpyxl.cell.Cell(worksheet2, value=element)
        # Write the cell to the worksheet, starting at cell A1
        worksheet2.append([cell])
        # Increment the row number
        row += 1

    # Save the changes
    writer.save()

def generate_execution_log():
    # Create a list to store the output lines
    output = []

    # Add the Problem representation in PuLP to the output
    output.append('Problem Statements')
    output.append(lp_prob)

    # Add the Optimization Results to the output
    output.append("Status:")
    output.append(pulp.LpStatus[lp_prob.status])
    output.append("Objective value:")
    output.append(pulp.value(lp_prob.objective))

    # output.append('Final Value of the Group Decision Variables')
    # for group in priority_groups:
    #        output.append(max_gap_percentage[group] + " - " + max_gap_percentage[group].value())

    # Return the output
    return output


"""
DATA PREPARATION
"""
# Get full path of Excel input file, and output choices
filepath, output_to_console, output_to_excel, skip_zero_requirements = select_input_file()
# Read the Excel file into a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
# source = print(filepath[(len(filepath)-15): (len(filepath)-5)])
# Get amount of additional funding
additional_funding = int(get_additional_funding())

# Extract the values from the dataframe and store them in list variables

# Number of projects# Number of projects
n = len(df)
# Names of projects
project_names = df['Project'].tolist()
# Requirements, gap, and allocation for each project
requirements = df['Requirements'].tolist()
gap = df['Gap'].tolist()
allocation = [0] * n
# Priority group for each project
priority = df['Group'].tolist()

# Calculate the gap percentage for each project
gap_percentage = []
for i in range(n):
    if requirements[i] == 0:
        gap_percentage.append(0)
    else:
        gap_percentage.append((gap[i] - allocation[i]) / requirements[i])


  


# Create a dictionary and associate a list of project indices to each priority group
unsorted_priority_groups = {}
for k, p in enumerate(priority):
    if p not in unsorted_priority_groups:
        unsorted_priority_groups[p] = []
    unsorted_priority_groups[p].append(k)

# Create a sorted version of the dictionary
priority_groups = {j: v for j, v in sorted(unsorted_priority_groups.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])}


"""
DECISION VARIABLES
"""
# Create a continuous Decision Variable and Affine Expression for the amount of additional funding received by each
# project
allocation = {}
allocation_expr = LpAffineExpression()
for z in range(n):
    if priority[z] == 'X' or (requirements[z] == 0 and skip_zero_requirements):
        # Projects in Priority Group 'X' don't get any allocation
        allocation[project_names[z]] = pulp.LpVariable(f'allocation_{project_names[z]}', lowBound=0, upBound=0)
    else:
        # allocation is non negative and cannot be greater than the initial gap
        allocation[project_names[z]] = pulp.LpVariable(f'allocation_{project_names[z]}', lowBound=0, upBound=(gap[z]*0.9))
    allocation_expr += allocation[project_names[z]]

# Create a continuous Decision Variable and Affine Expression for the maximum GAP% within each priority group
#target_group_A = {}
target_group_A_expr = LpAffineExpression()
target_group_A = pulp.LpVariable(f'allocation', lowBound=0 )
target_group_A_expr += target_group_A


#project_gap_perc = {}
#project_gap_perc_expr = LpAffineExpression()
#for z in range(n):
#    if priority[z] == 'X' or (requirements[z] == 0 and skip_zero_requirements):
#        # Projects in Priority Group 'X' don't get any allocation
#        project_gap_perc[project_names[z]] = pulp.LpVariable(f'project_gap_perc_{project_names[z]}', lowBound=0, upBound=0)
#    else:
#        # allocation is non negative and cannot be greater than the initial gap
#        project_gap_perc[project_names[z]] = pulp.LpVariable(f'project_gap_perc{project_names[z]}', lowBound=0, upBound=gap[z]/requirements[z])
#    project_gap_perc_expr += project_gap_perc[project_names[z]]



"""
LINEAR PROGRAMMING PROBLEM
"""
# Create the linear programming problem object
lp_prob = pulp.LpProblem('Multi-Objective Optimization', pulp.LpMaximize)



"""
OBJECTIVE FUNCTIONS
"""
# Define the objective function as an LpAffineExpression
obj = LpAffineExpression()
# MAXIMIZE the portion of additional funding allocated to projects
obj += allocation_expr
# MINIMIZE the Max GAP% within each group [actually Maximizing the -(Max GAP%)]
obj += -target_group_A_expr
# MINIMIZE the Max GAP% within each group [actually Maximizing the -(Max GAP%)]
#obj += -project_gap_perc_expr
# Set the Objective Function
lp_prob += obj



"""
CONSTRAINTS
"""
# Additional funding allocations to individual projects must be non-negative and not greater than the project's gap
#for v in range(n):
#    lp_prob += allocation[project_names[v]] <= gap[v]
#    lp_prob += allocation[project_names[v]] >= 0

# The sum of allocations to individual projects cannot be greater than the additional funding
lp_prob += pulp.lpSum([allocation[project_names[u]] for u in range(n)]) <= additional_funding

# The Max GAP % within each group >= of the GAP % of all projects in the group (proxy for dynamic max calculation)
for i, (p, group) in enumerate(priority_groups.items()):
    # Get the indices of the projects in the group
    group_indices = priority_groups[p] #selects the indices matching with the rows of the projects belonging to that group
    # Iterate over the indices of the projects in the group
    for index in group:
        # Create an LpAffineExpression for the GAP% of the project
        project_gap_percentage = LpAffineExpression()
        if requirements[index] == 0:
            project_gap_percentage += 0
        else:
            project_gap_percentage += (gap[index] - allocation[project_names[index]]) / requirements[index]
            # Add constraint to the model
        lp_prob +=  target_group_A == (project_gap_percentage/pow(delta_gap, i))

#for i, (p, group) in enumerate(priority_groups.items()):
#    group_indices = priority_groups[p]
#    for index in group[1: len(group)]:
#        # Create an LpAffineExpression for the GAP% of the project
#        project_gap_percentage = LpAffineExpression()
#        if requirements[index] == 0:
#            project_gap_percentage += 0
#        else:
#            project_gap_percentage += (gap[index-1] - allocation[project_names[index-1]]) / requirements[index-1]
#            project_gap_percentage += (gap[index] - allocation[project_names[index]]) / requirements[index]
#            # Add constraint to the model
#        lp_prob +=  project_gap_perc[index] == project_gap_perc[index-1]


## The Max GAP % of a lower priority group should not be lower than Max GAP % of higher priority groups
#for i, (p, group) in enumerate(priority_groups.items()):
#    if i == 0:
#        # Skip the first group (group A)
#        #lp_prob+=max_gap_percentage[p]== 0.70
#        continue
#    # Get the parameter for the current group (p) and the immediately preceding group (prev_p)
#    prev_p = list(priority_groups.keys())[i - 1]
#    lp_prob += max_gap_percentage[p] >= max_gap_percentage[prev_p] * delta_gap


"""
PROGRAMMING MODEL SOLVER
"""
# Solve the linear programming problem
lp_prob.solve()


"""
OPUTPUT
"""
execution_log = generate_execution_log()

if output_to_console:
    print_to_console(execution_log)

if output_to_excel:
    print_to_excel(execution_log)




import sys
sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()
```

delta_gap and the additional_funding are external parameters.
I receive even negative allocations and the constrains are not always meet, e.g. in group B, C I reach level of funding gap much lower than the level of group A- sometimes they apparently randomly go to zero. How can this be possible?

I am trying with additional budget of 5, 2.6 and 1 billion.

I am considering using another library, any suggestions?

Comment: this is tough to troubleshoot because there is no data.  Can you edit your post to include more of your code and either the real data or some toy data so that it executes and shows the behavior that you find problematic?  Ideally, somebody who could help you should be able to copy your code from your post, run it, and see the problem.  If the code is "big" then making a "toy example" is usually the way to go.  What you have above is fine, but it would be helpful if it was all-inclusive w/ data.

Comment: Also, have you tried to print the problem to inspect it to see if it matches your math expressions and expectations?  Try `print(lp_prob)` before solving it and read through what is produced.

Comment: Many thanks, I have modified the question including the entire script, so that it can be easily debugged. Also, you can find here: we.tl/t-dOh1l6sH0u the sample dataset I am using to test it. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok.  I think the pendulum swung in the opposite direction there!  Not all of that is needed to work the optimization you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that I think might help you.  I ginned up some sample data that I think represents the problem.  I'm not sure how to get your actual data.  There are a couple variations of this you might explore, based on how you handle different cases.  This tries to lower the entire "gap ceiling" with the ratios you defined.  One of the byproducts of that is that if there is a large gap in the lesser priority projects, but very little gap in 'A' (the high priority stuff) then the lesser ones will get funded to close the ratio.

You should try it for largely varying values of `total_funds` as suggested in the comments to see performance.

#### Code:

```
import pulp
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

# DATA   

# below could be from dataframe or whatever....
#           Group : Project : (current funds, requirement)
data =     { 'A' : { 'z19': (50, 100),
                     'x40': (60, 100)},
             'B' : { 'r55': (80, 84),
                     'm21': (100, 200),
                     'm22': (100, 300)},
             'C' : { 'k15': (40, 40),       
                     'p88': (10, 20)}}

# some housekeeping to prep data...
groups = list(data.keys())
projects = []
projects_by_group = defaultdict(list)
reqts = {}
funds = {}
for grp in groups:
    for project, (fund, req) in data[grp].items():
        projects.append(project)
        projects_by_group[grp].append(project)
        reqts[project] = req
        funds[project] = fund

# make some group multipliers as a convenience...
multipliers = {grp: 1.1**groups.index(grp) for grp in groups}

tot_funds = 40 

# LP PROBLEM
prob = pulp.LpProblem('allocation', pulp.LpMinimize)

# VARIABLES

gap_ceiling = pulp.LpVariable('max_ceil') 
add_funds        = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('add_funds', projects, lowBound=0)

# OBJECTIVE:  Minimize the "gap cieling" across all projects by minimizing 

prob += gap_ceiling

# CONSTRAINTS:

prob += pulp.lpSum(add_funds[project] for project in projects) <= tot_funds

for project in projects:
    prob += add_funds[project] + funds[project] <= reqts[project]

for grp in groups:
    for project in projects_by_group[grp]:
        prob += gap_ceiling * multipliers[grp] >= (reqts[project] - add_funds[project] - funds[project])/reqts[project]

results = prob.solve()

for grp in groups:
    print(f'{grp} gap_cieling: {gap_ceiling.value() * multipliers[grp]: 0.2f} (actual: {max((reqts[project] - add_funds[project].value() - funds[project])/reqts[project] for project in projects_by_group[grp]) : 0.2f})')

for project in projects:
    print(f'{project} + {add_funds[project].value() : 0.2f}')
```

#### Output:

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc /var/folders/rt/5gc2md7s7y5bw8ddt74tz5vw0000gp/T/e6935f1e09064df28e4bd83074cc74c6-pulp.mps timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution /var/folders/rt/5gc2md7s7y5bw8ddt74tz5vw0000gp/T/e6935f1e09064df28e4bd83074cc74c6-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 20 COLUMNS
At line 50 RHS
At line 66 BOUNDS
At line 68 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 15 rows, 8 columns and 28 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Presolve 4 (-11) rows, 4 (-4) columns and 9 (-19) elements
0  Obj 0.38484848 Primal inf 22.352719 (4)
5  Obj 0.48837209
Optimal - objective value 0.48837209
After Postsolve, objective 0.48837209, infeasibilities - dual 0 (0), primal 0 (0)
Optimal objective 0.488372093 - 5 iterations time 0.002, Presolve 0.00
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

A gap_cieling:  0.49 (actual:  0.49)
B gap_cieling:  0.54 (actual:  0.54)
C gap_cieling:  0.59 (actual:  0.50)
z19 +  1.16
x40 +  0.00
r55 +  0.00
m21 +  0.00
m22 +  38.84
k15 +  0.00
p88 +  0.00
[Finished in 92ms]
```